# Laravel whereMorph query not working in laravel-10

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, polymorphism, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('creater_id')->nullable();
$table->string('creater_type')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('updater_id')->nullable();
$table->string('updater_type')->nullable();
$table->unsignedBigInteger('deleter_id')->nullable();
$table->string('deleter_type')->nullable();
```

```
public function creater()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
public function updater()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
public function deleter()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

```
function dm(){
    return auth()->guard('dm')->user();
}
```

```
public function index(): View
    {
        $data['lams'] = LocalAreaManager::with('creater')->whereMorph('creater_type', get_class(dm()), 'creater_id')->latest()->get();
        return view('district_manager.lam_management.index', $data);
    }
```

**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'morph' in 'where clause'**

Give me an error :

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'morph' in 'where clause'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must use creatable and updatable and deletable instead creater and updater and deleter in your Model

for example in laravel documentation :

```
public function imageable(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```